# MaaS Hyper-v Power Type

Tags: maas, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V 2012 R2 Host that has Ubuntu 14.04 running MaaS 1.9.1 as a Guest VM. This has works well until I need to commission a virtual node as it requires a Power Type to be used to turn on the VM. The virtual machine can't use Wake-On-LAN down to the fact it cant communicate via TCP so does anyone have any other ideas how I can configure the Power Type.

I tried installing [MaaS Hyper-V power adapter](https://github.com/gabriel-samfira/hyperv-power-adapter) but it doesn't support MaaS 1.9 and just broke the MaaS web interface.

Comment: You're trying to use Maas inside a virtual machine, and commision other virtual machines?  If so, that's intriguing.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to test drive OpenStack and don't have the budget for [5 machines](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot). This idea of using MaaS inside a virtual machine is supported using [VMware](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive)

Comment: Yeah, I can see maas working fine, but I don't see how you're going to be able to commission virtual machines, when they are in the off state, which is required by maas.  If you find a way, please update the post.

Comment: I suggest voting for this feature at https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1631129
to increase priority for MAAS 2.x development [How-To-Vote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQG7s.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I installed [Wake-On-LAN Virtual Machine](http://www.yarovy.com/wolvm/index.html) on my Hyper-V server  which listens for Wake-On-LAN magic packets and starts up the appropriate VM according to the MAC address. This means my Power Type in MaaS is Wake-On-LAN and I was able to commission my VM.